# Why "ls" command is not working on Windows CMD while working on VS Code Terminal?

Tags: windows, cmd, visual-studio-code

"ls" command is not working on my windows cmd while it is working on visual studio code. Can you please tell me why ?

E:\ls

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code opens up a `powershell` terminal by default, which translates `ls` into the `Get-ChildItem` commandlet.

Windows *cmd.exe* doesn't do this - the closest equivalent would be `dir`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to make it work in windows cmd ?

Comment: Bit of a hacky solution, but you could create a new file called ls.cmd which has "@powershell -command Get-ChildItem %1 %2 %3 %4 %5" (excl quotes) as the contents. Then running ls from a command prompt would in turn run this file, which launches powershell in the background. I've add %1..%5 just to pass through the first 5 parameters.